# Inheritance in UIViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller

I'm working over inheriting UIViewControllers but am facing issues with it. Heres the list of ViewControllers I've used and their flow.

**Header Files**

```
MainViewController : UIViewController {

}
```

---

```
CustomerTicketViewController : UIViewController {

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *listTickets;
```

---

```
CustomerEditTicketViewController : CustomerTicketViewController {

}
```

---

**Implementation Files**

```
@implementation MainViewController

- (void)loadCustomer {
        CustomerTicketViewController *customerTicketViewController = [[CustomerTicketViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomerTicketViewController" bundle:nil];
        [customerTicketViewController setListTickets:myTickets];
        [self presentModalViewController:customerTicketViewController animated:YES];
        [customerTicketViewController release];
}

@end
```

---

```
@implementation CustomerTicketViewController

    - (void)editCustomer {
        CustomerEditTicketViewController *customerEditTicketViewController = [[CustomerEditTicketViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomerEditTicketViewController" bundle:nil];
        NSLog(@"ParentView.listTickets: %@", listTickets);
        [self presentModalViewController:customerEditTicketViewController animated:NO];
        [customerEditTicketViewController release];
    }

    @end
```

---

```
@implementation CustomerEditTicketViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSLog(@"listTickets: %@", listTickets);
    NSLog(@"super.listTickets: %@", super.listTickets);
    NSLog(@"self->listTickets: %@", self->listTickets);
    NSLog(@"self.listTickets: %@", self.listTickets);
}

@end
```

---

The logs in the sub class print null but as per my understanding they should print the same values as in the ParentView.
Please guide me if I'm wrong at some place.

```
    ParentView.listTickets: (
    "<CustomerTicket: 0x4c75d90>",
    "<CustomerTicket: 0x4c76310>"
)

listTickets: (null)
super.listTickets: (null)
self->listTickets: (null)
self.listTickets: (null)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your edit view controller is a separate object. All it inherits from the superclass is the fact that it has an array property called listTickets,, not the *value* of the property. This is a (the?) fundamental point in object oriented programming.

You have to set the value after creating the view controller just as you do when creating the first one:

```
CustomerEditTicketViewController *customerEditTicketViewController = [[CustomerEditTicketViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomerEditTicketViewController" bundle:nil];

customerEditTicketViewController.listTickets = self.listTickets;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your view controller's editCustomer method never makes an assignment to the property of the child controller.